# Method returns always the same result

Tags: ruby, methods, hash

I want to create a code to name organic chemestry compounds. There's the script I wrote below:

```
 class Molecule
carbon_number_name = { 1 => 'met', 2 => 'et', 3=> 'prop', 4 => 'but'}; bonds = {1 => 'ano', 2 => 'eno', 3 => 'ino'}
 x = Molecule.new
def molecule(hidrogen, carbon_numbers)
    @carbon_numbers = carbon_numbers
    @hidrogen = hidrogen
    if hidrogen =  2*(carbon_numbers)
     return 2
    elsif hidrogen = 2*(carbon_numbers) + 2
     return 1
    else 
     return 3
end
end
puts carbon_number_name[carbon_numbers] + bonds[x.molecule(hidrogen,carbon_numbers)]
```

The method "molecule" isn't working as expected: its ever returning "2", despite of the conditions. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Actually, there is an      end 
statement, I just missed pasting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing elements in your ifs statements, just assigning them to hidrogen.

To compare two objects use == method